# Otto for Android is like Go-to

Tags: android

Otto library is now used in the project I'm working on. I had to debug a certain thing and it was quite hard to find out why certain code was executed.

Isn't it Otto a little bit like `goto`? I mean we can execute the code whenever we want from the places completely unrelated to that code and the only evidence of this is annotation. Labels in `goto` are even more visible.

Basically the question is - is the usage of event buses acceptable in the projects?

Answer (score 1):

Yes usage of EventBus is acceptable and even more like required in big production projects. Because of it makes code less. Problem is not EventBus is way HOW it's used.

EventBus is just simple and fast way instead of define a lot of interfaces.

Your problem is more like coding style things. Code is not clear and you cannot undestod what is going on and where.

Comment: Partly I do agree with you, but can't the same be said about `goto` ? It just feels like it doesn't belong to procedural programming like we know it.

Comment: goto is just taboo in programming. That's all. Maybe if we will check out some old C style programs we will find awesome easy to understand code.  But history shows many fool's can easily shot their foot using goto.